# Create FOSElasticaBundle action in controller

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I decided to deal with ElasticSearch. Immediately faced with the problem of writing action in the controller. Here is my configuration. Can someone write a small example of how to use this bundle for these fields

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
```

Comment: Anything wrong with the official documentation? https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md

Comment: @zerkms i try, but still nothing to get (

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command to populate the indexes `php app/console fos:elastica:populate`

Then to lookup your users you can use in your controller action :

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.search.user');

// Option 1. Returns all users who have example.net in any of their mapped fields
$results = $finder->find('example.net');
```

like in the docs normally it's self explanatory :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md

We might help if you have problem in your code if it doesn't work if you want an example it is already there i just copied paste it since there isn't much to add.